# How to download an excel file in Safari-Mac-Desktop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, excel, safari, blob

## Hello JavaScripters,

I'm trying to download a blob file with type xlsx (excel) in Safari. I did this:

```
obReader = new FileReader();
obReader.onload = function(e) {
    obdata = btoa(obReader.result);
    obDatauri = 'data:' + isbContentType + ';base64,' + obdata;
    window.location = obDatauri; 
};
obReader.readAsBinaryString(iobBLOB);
```

This code above downloads pdf and txt files but when I use to download an excel file it doesn't works.

The var *iobBLOB* has the blob and *isbContentType* has the Content-Type, I have been used this ones:

- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/force-download
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

and others seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)

---

The Blob files has this type:

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

**Tested on a Macbook pro, Safari 9.03**

---

Note: This code works on ChromeiOS and Safari (iPhone)

## Thanks for the help!

Comment: `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated. Also why not just use `readAsDataURL`?

Comment: ok, thanks @Musa for that. But i'm updated now and it happends the same. Look the fileReader result is like this: `"data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,..."` and it downloads but with no extension.

Comment: @EsNoguera You wanted to reply to Musa, not me.

Comment: @rmaddy yes man, excuse me